# Is this incorrect way to implement asynchronous method

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I work in LAN application, this application will receive connection from many client
in many situation, I have to ensure that the client which I try to communicate with , It's already connected before sending any data to it, so I create List of currently connected client, and a method to send "test-packet" continuously, as follows
I separate the Main UI Thread from The other's thread That I Will refer to it later
 I create public class for managing the communication process

```
public class Listner
{
  static TcpListener Listnerobj;
  static List<Client> Online;
  public static int port;
  public static void BeginListening()
   {
      Online = new Online(50);
      Listnerobj= new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
      Listnerobj.Start();
      System.Threading.Thread PingerH = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PingX));
   }
}
```

again I created the thread PingerH to separate the main UI thread and communication process

```
private static async void PingX()
{
    while(_ping)
    {
        await PingAll();
        await CheckWhoAreDisConnected();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

the method PingAll Iterate Through all Online list Item and send test packet
the client will replay "just echo" the test packet and the LastPing field will be updated
the method CheckWhoAreDisConnected check for LastPing field in the Client Class
if the subtraction of DateTime.Now and LastPing is more than 200 seconds then
that client is disconnected so the CheckWhoAreDisConnected method will remove it from Online list
I create two thread,one of them check for data Avaliable in the network stream
and the other check for pending attempt from new client if(Listnerobj.Pending())
Is this Incorrect way to implement asynchronous patterns side by side with multithreading ?
generally, does the application logic is good or bad ?
Do I made a mistake?

Comment: For code reviews post your question here: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: thank you, I don't know there are code review section, but what about mixing the asynchronous with multithreading ?

Comment: This is a general question, not a problem. Go to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and you'll get answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement your asynchronous method correctly you don't need to run it in a separate thread. Make the return type `Task` as `void` returning async methods swallow all exceptions and are usually reserved for event handlers only. Instead of `Thread.Sleep` use `await Task.Delay`. The former blocks a thread, the later waits asynchronously without blocking a thread. For best practices, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

```
private static async Task PingX()
{
    while(_ping)
    {
        await PingAll();
        await CheckWhoAreDisConnected();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

I'd also change my `BeginListening` method to return a `Task` and `await PingX()`

```
public static Task BeginListening()
{
   Online = new Online(50);
   Listnerobj= new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
   Listnerobj.Start();
   await PingX();
 }
```

Comment: thank you Mr.Ned, but the purpose of separate thread is that the main thread does a lot of work by receiving the data from these method and viewing it in the main UI,thank you for these guidance about how to use task's properly, please inform me about if it will be a "performance overhead" if I continue using this way of "multithreading with asynchronous"

Comment: Using the extra thread does use 1MB of thread local storage, you can use `await Task.Run(async () => await PingX())` to run the code on a thread pool thread, which won't create the extra thread.

Comment: even if these method uses an infinite loop ? as you can see, this methods uses infinite loop as this job should be repeated again and again as far as the application running

Comment: The `while` loop will only run until it reaches an `await` statement and then it will be suspended until the awaited statement is finished. This will free up the current thread to do other work. But if you want a dedicated thread you can use `TaskFactory.StartNew` with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.